# Hadoop 3.2.1 Multinode Cluster Nodemanager is not running

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

I have Hadoop 3.2.1 installed on Ubuntu 16.04lts and my cluster has 18 datanodes and 1 master.
After running:

```
$ start-dfs.sh
$ start-yarn.sh
$ jps
```

On master I get the following:

```
ResourceManager
NameNode
SecondaryNameNodecode
jps
```

And on datanodes:

```
DataNode
jps
```

All the nodes seems to be live:
[NameNode Overview Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAEW.png)

But when I reach the Cluster overview, none of my datanodes seems to be active:
[Cluster Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSKhY.png)

My configurations files:

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/data/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/data/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The namenode and datanode directories exists on every host (master and datanodes)

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services </name>
<value> mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Also I have configured hadoop-env.sh for JAVA_HOME Path and all the other variables are in .bashrc file (also in every host).

I have modified the /etc/hosts file to include all the hosts with their IPs and hostnames and finally I have also modified the workers file to include all the IPs of the datanodes.

The first time I have formatted the NameNode, the directories for the hdfs-site.xml was wrong (I had the datanode dir twice), so hdfs make its own directories under /tmp/hdfs/ (if I remember correctly). But I fixed this with formating again the NameNode with the corect directories.